# Multiple users with different views, on a iOS app?

Tags: ios, view

I have created an app that have multiple users profiles, there are common views for all profiles, there are specific views for specific profiles, and there are views that are graphically equal but they refer to difference source of information.

for example:

- news : each user receives news but the information of the new is different for each user
- portfolio : all users can see the same portfolio of the company
- statistics : this view is only able for the administrator.

in the moment i have:

- Use the same story board for all my UIViews
- I have a `UITabBarController` for each user
- In the login view I segue to a `UITabBarController` depend of the type of user.
- For the views that are common for all users I have use a `UIContainerViewController` for each one.   because if I send from multiple `UITabBarCOntroller` a segue to a single view don't works.

the problems that I have in this moment are.

- The story board with all views this views is becoming slower time by time.(i have 30 views on my app)
- Is difficult to reuse views.

I would like to know if there is a better way for doing this.

Thanks, sorry for my bad eMnglish.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

You can use multiple storyboards and instantiate the views you need from each one.  You would probably split your storyboard into logical sections such as settings.storyboard, profile.storyboard and so on.

For views which will be used in multiple view controllers, you do not want to recreate it for each view controller.  That is too much work and when you have changes, you have to make them in multiple places.  It is best to create a .xib file which will hold a view that gets reused in multiple controllers, such as a UITableViewCell or a custom UIView which many view controllers can embed in their view hierarchy.

You can look up how to load a storyboard programmatically and instantiate a view controller from it.  You can also look up how to instantiate a view from a xib.